# html/css: loading bar (with buffer)

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

Can you guys help me in tweaking out my loading bar css and/or html. I've got two problems existing right now with my current loading bar.

One is that there is some excess shadow going out of the bar in the left and right outside the border (which makes it look like the border-radius is pixelated when zoomed properly). I know it's the `box-shadow`'s problem cause it's not there when I remove the box shadow property for both `#progress` and `#buffer`.

[image: excess shadow screenshot]

And another is quite minor but is really bugging me. When the progress/buffer bar is just starting to load (change `style="width:0.4%"`), the form of the div with radius goes outside the container:

[image: div goes outside container]

I know I can `overflow:hidden` it (which I already do in the `#loading_bar_container`), but I think `position:absolute` doesn't want to get hidden (which I need absolute cause I need the two bars to be in one position, overlapping each other). When I remove though the `#buffer` (so there's only one bar), and remove `loading_bar`'s `position:relative` and `#progress` 's `position:absolute`, I get the scenario I want which is:

[image]

I'll add here a [jsfiddle fragment](http://jsfiddle.net/index/VeJNt/) of the code so we can play with it.

Cheers!

PS: I think tag should be loading-bar but I can't create a new tag so I add it as progress-bar.

**Edit:** I've done this test in Chrome and @Oriol mentioned it works well in FF. I've checked and FF does display it the way I wanted it to. I've checked with Safari and it displays the same was as Chrome. So this question is for Chrome and Safari so far. Haven't checked it with IE (scared).

Comment: For whatever (JS?) is updating the width of the progress bar, you can just cast it to an integer, so you don't have to deal with small pieces. Or, if you want x.x% still, you can just force anything <1.0 to 1, and let the rest be floats.

Comment: Yep. It's javascript. And well, I want it to be more flexible. Having the width 660px overall is just for example. So I really don't want to compute what width would it be in order to exceed the border-radius part.

Comment: On Firefox your code works well. Maybe it's a Chrome bug?

Comment: Hi @Oriol, you're right. I forgot to check on other browsers but yah I was using Chrome in doing this and the screenshots. I've checked with other browsers now and it seems only firefox was displaying it the way I wanted to. And I still haven't checked IE behavior. XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's a Chrome's bug caused by `position:relative`.

Compare http://jsfiddle.net/VeJNt/2/ with http://jsfiddle.net/VeJNt/3/

Then you can use

```
#progress {
    margin-top:-8px;
}​
```

instead of those `position:relative` and `position:absolute`.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/VeJNt/4/

But why do you have both `loading_bar_container` and `loading_bar`?

I think you should simplify your code: http://jsfiddle.net/VeJNt/5/

**Edit:**

If you want a more general code, which doesn't depend on the number of bars, you can use

```
#loading_bar>div {
  border-radius:7px;
  height:100%;
  width:0%;
  margin-top:-8px;
}
#loading_bar>div:first-child {
  margin-top:0;
}
```

And then you only have to set the `background` and `box-shadow` to each bar.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/VeJNt/6/

It isn't cumulative (-8px to the second bar, -16px to the third one, ...) because when you set a margin it isn't like if you are setting `position:relative` and setting `top` to -8px, -16px...

If you set `margin-top:10px` to an element, it goes 10px down, but doesn't overlap the next element (all the following elements go 10px down too).

Then, if you set `margin-top:-8px` to the second bar, it goes 8px up, but it doesn't appear any space between it and the next bar (all the following bars go 8px up too).
Then, you don't have to set `margin-top:-16px` to the third bar, you only need -8px, because it has gone up 8px already because of the second bar.

Comment: Cool! Saw the `margin-top` fiddle already. Looks like that will work. Will try it in my code.

Comment: And yeah. I've been meaning to change the code as well to remove some few divs. Can't remember why I had another containing one. I think it was for the border before or something like there is a script tied to the `#loading_bar` and not the `#loading_bar_container`

Comment: Awesome! Works wonders. Another thing learned, I can do div overlaps by using negatives. Didn't know that, I thought the only way was using positions relative and absolute. Thanks!

Comment: Re fiddle6: Cool! But how did that happen? Like, why were the other divs (bar3,4) get to be in the same position when they only got margin-top:-8px? Shouldn't it be something like cumulative?

Comment: @index At the beginning I didn't like the solution very much because I thought the same, but then I realized that we can set `margin-top:-8px` to all bars (instead the first) because it's margin. I have edited my answer adding the explanation.

Comment: Heh!You're right. Awesome! And +1 for that neat trick with explanation. Thanks!