# display multiple child DIVs stacked

Tags: html, css

I have a progress bar which should show multiple values at the same time
an example may look like this:
[image: progress bar]

I **don't** want:

- to micro adjust (like `margin-top: -20px`)
- use vendor prefixes (like `display: -webkit-inline-box;`)

html:

```
<div id="progress">
  <div id="progress-buffer"></div>
  <div id="progress-time"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#progress {
  background: #333;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}
#progress-buffer {
  background: orange;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
#progress-time {
  background: green;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sQ26G/1/)

Comment: If you're using jQuery you can do it easily by changing the `width` and `left` position as necessary. [Here is an example of that tactic](http://jsfiddle.net/cTTPP/13/). You'd make each of them siblings, not children though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, added to what you already got.

```
#progress
{
    position:relative;
}

#progress-buffer, #progress-time 
{
    position:absolute;
}
```

The first `position:relative;` makes sure the subsequent `position:absolute;` are relative to `#progress`.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2KA2a/).

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I answered a question like yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12186027/1529630

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/VeJNt/5/

HTML:

```
<div id="loading_bar">
    <div id="buffer" style="width:40%"></div>
    <div id="progress" style="width:0.5%"></div>
    <!-- You can add as much as you want, but they
         must be sorted from wider to shorter  -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 5px;
}

#loading_bar {
  border:1px solid #222;
  border-radius:7px;
  background-color:#666;
  width:660px;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:8px;
}

#buffer, #progress {
  border-radius:7px;
  height:100%;
  width:0%;
}

#buffer {
  box-shadow:1px 0 8px #000;
  background-color:#0474C0;
}

#progress {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;
  background-color:pink;
  margin-top:-8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would just be to add float: left; to each of the child divs in the parent.  That will give you the "stacking" you want.

Comment: That's not much easier than my answer, and makes it more complicated to calculate the width of each child element.